# return and while in function

Tags: c#, function, while-loop, return

This function accepting input and telling the user whether the input is number or not a number.

```
static string isnum()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Write a number please");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        string nums = "123456789";
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] == nums[j])
                {
                    cnt++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cnt == a.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + "  is a number");
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + "  is not a number");
            return "";
        } 
}


isnum();
```

I would like this function to repeat herself if the input is not a number, till the input will be a number, and then to stop.
This function working now, but she's working only one time.
When I'm trying to add a while block to the function to make her run again and again till the input is number I'm getting the "not all code paths return a value" error.

is it  because a "return" statement ends a function, and therefore prevent her to run again?
how can I solve that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I would also hazard a guess that a `0` is legal in numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this with creating a loop arround it and do not return when it's not a number.

```
static string isnum()
{
    // just loop forever.
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a number please");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        string nums = "123456789";
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] == nums[j])
                {
                    cnt++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cnt == a.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + "  is a number");
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + "  is not a number");
            // don't return here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best approach is to use do while because you want your code to at least run once.

you have one problem in your code which is returning when variable is not a number. see these modifications:

```
static string isnum()
{
    do{
        Console.WriteLine("Write a number please");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        string nums = "123456789";
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] == nums[j])
                {
                    cnt++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cnt == a.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + "  is a number");
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + "  is not a number");
        } 
    }while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it in a while loop, and loop until the result is a number:

```
string result = "";
while (result == "")
{
    result = isnum();
}
Console.WriteLine("result is a number: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *looping* you can try *querying* the `a` string with a help of Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

...

static string isnum() {
  // Keep asking user until he/she provides a number
  while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Write a number please");
    string a = Console.ReadLine();

    // Number is 
    //   1. Has at least one character
    //   2. All characters of number are digits
    if (a.Length > 0 && a.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
      Console.WriteLine($"{a} is a number");

      // we have a proper number, let's return int 
      return a;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{a} is not a number");
  }
}
```

Comment: Another option is `if (a != null && a.Any() && a.All(char.IsDigit))`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: `IsDigit` is often *too wide*, it returns `true` for *any Unicode digit*, say for *Persian* digits: `۰۱۲` is a valid number according to `IsDigit`

Comment: So, not an overly useful operator...